# Binding dynamic form elements in partial view - index out of range error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an MVC 4 app with a form on razor view. One page allows user to 'add another' as many times as needed. The added row is a partial view, though it doesn't have to be.  I am using the number of added rows as the index.  I get the error in the partial view, on the first attempt to add a row. Near as I can tell, the index value is 0, so not sure why it is out of range.

Ajax call to controller:

```
$("#add-item").on("click", function () {
    var index = $('.accessoryRow').length;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Accessory/AddItem',
        cache: false,
        data: { index: index },
        success: function (html) {
            $("#form-body").append(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Form body:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Accessory", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="form-body">

    </div>
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model EmployeeHardwareRequest.Models.ViewModels.AccessoryVM

@{
        var i = Model.lineIndex;
    }

<div class="accessoryRow">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })*@
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Accessories[i].AccessoryId, Model.AccessoryDdl, new { @class = "form-control accessoryList" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductLink, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })*@
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestedAccessories[i].ProductLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter link to web page" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestedAccessory.ProductLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            @*@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("AccessoryVM"))
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestedAccessory.ProductLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter link to web page" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestedAccessory.ProductLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" id="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller that serves up the partial:

```
    public ActionResult AddItem(int index)
    {
        AccessoryVM model = new AccessoryVM();
        int selectedAcc = 1;

        List<Accessory> accessories = _db.Accessory.ToList();  // change this to use the accessoryDTO

        List<int> monitorSizeList = new List<int>  // replace this with data from db table.
        {
            20, 22, 24, 27
        };

        model.lineIndex = index;

        model.AccessoryDdl = new SelectList(accessories, "AccessoryId", "ItemDescription", selectedAcc);
        model.MonitorSizeDdl = new SelectList(monitorSizeList, "Select Monitor Size");
        return PartialView("_NewItem", model);
    }
```

So the theory is, the button is clicked to add a row, the ajax function reads the number of rows, passes that index to the controller, which adds it to the model to be sent to the partial, where it is integrated into the html, for model binding.  The row is added, and if the add button is clicked again, the cycle starts again, but this time the index is one, because of the added row.

I honestly don't care how I achieve this goal (within reason, I'm not going to scrap everything and go with a different technology).  If there is a "standard" way of doing this in MVC, I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddItem` controller action you don't seem to be populating the `RequestedAccessories` and `Accessories` properties of your view model and yet in the view you are trying to access them:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Accessories[i].AccessoryId, Model.AccessoryDdl, new { @class = "form-control accessoryList" })
```

and here:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestedAccessories[i].ProductLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter link to web page" } })
```

So make sure that you have populated those collections with the corresponding elements if you expect to access them.

By the way a better approach in this case is to use non-sequential indices as illustrated in [`this blog post`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). This makes it much easier to dynamically add elements. You can also check this [`nifty little HTML helper`](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) that will make it even easier.

Comment: Thanks Darin for the quick response. The dropdown is populated in the controller, but I'm not sure what you are referring to with populating the RequsestedAccessories collection, because there is nothing to populate it with. Am I missing a concept here?

Comment: What do you mean there's nothing to populate it with? How do you expect to be able to access this collection in your view by index if you don't have any elements in it? You should populate this collection with the elements that are already added by the user so far + add one empty element in it which will represent the newly added row. But I strongly recommend you reading the blog post I have refereed to in my answer for a much easier and better way to implement this,

Comment: and thanks for the links.   I tried Steve's way, but kept getting a "null object error on the model reference in the foreach, I assume because that is the procedure for displaying, not entering new, because of course there is nothing in the model, if the form has not been filled out yet.  But again, I feel I am missing some basic concept here.

Comment: ... there is nothing to populate it with, because the form has not been filled out yet, so there is no "what the user has added so far..."

Comment: In this case make sure that have tested in your view that `i > 0` before trying to render any input elements and accessing the collections. Obviously this will work only the first time when there are no elements being added yet. When you subsequently call the `AddItem` action you will need to populate the collections as I already explained in my answer.